# Touch Punch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, touch-punch

I am making an HTML5 app with jQuery Mobile, and I just added the touch punch capability to the app. The website (http://touchpunch.furf.com/) works perfectly in my cellphone, but when I try to apply the same techniques into my app, the draggable function does not work correctly.

Here is my head of the code, so you guys can check whether I am inserting the correct jquery sources.

```
<head> 
<title>Parking Lot App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/florida_tech.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>   <!-- TOUCH PUNCH -->

</head>
```

This is the code where the content is being displayed. It just an image with 2 green blocks within a 'div'

```
  <div data-role="content" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px">

  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="position:relative; height: 347px">
      <div style=" position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px">    
           <img src="style/pic.png" alt="Parking Lot Map"/>

      </div>
      <div style="background-color:green; width:17px; height:35px; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 31px; left: 81px ">
                                &nbsp
      </div>
      <div style="background-color:green; width:17px; height:35px; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 31px; left: 102px ">
                                &nbsp
      </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe jQueryUI library and jQuery Mobile library are conflicting with each other.
I made sample code from your code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Parking Lot App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/florida_tech.min.css" />-->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />-->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div data-role="content" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px">

   <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="position:relative; height: 347px">
    <div style=" position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px"> 
     <img src="style/pic.png" alt="Parking Lot Map"/>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:green; width:17px; height:35px; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 31px; left: 81px ">&nbsp</div>
    <div style="background-color:green; width:17px; height:35px; z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 31px; left: 102px ">&nbsp</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   $('#draggable').draggable();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This code works on my iPad mini(iOS6) and laptop browsers(Chrome, Safari etc.). In the code above, I commented out stylesheets ("themes/florida_tech.min.css" and "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css"). In my environment, "jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" can conflicts with jQueryUI. When I commented out this stylesheet, everything worked well.